# How to sort a column which contains server-side generated values othr than database values in jQuery Datatables.?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, datatable

I am using `jQuery Datatables` for one of my page to display data.I am using `server-side scripting` to display datatables.

In my html I have **8 columns**.5 columns for fetched values and other 3 contains `some mathematics calculations with php functions` that I am returning in the server side script.Those are not depends on database fields.

I changed $output[] to add my generated values and all are work fine.

What my problem is I need to `sort columns that have generated values`.But this is not possible because datatables mysql ordering statement makes error because these columns are not in actual mysql table.

So how would I able to do sorting above fields? Do we have any sorting that I can do for those columns without interfering mysql ordering clause(may be sort in client side).

Thanks.

Comment: Fetch it from a jquery post via the jQuery data tables.

Comment: @Darren Thanks for your comment. Didn't get you right.can you please describe it.